# facebook connections between different people

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to find if two people are connected with in 2-3 levels (n to be precise) using facebook apis? if they are connected, is there a way to get the different possible paths? 
If not, what is the maximum depth permitted? I am guessing we can find atleast 2 levels as we can manually match the friend list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, depending on each persons security level and their acceptance of your app, you can determine it using the API.

You will need to get `read_friendlists` permission from the app user.

Examples:

```
OK  : Me (authd app)  -> my friend             -> their friend (authd app)
OK  : Me (authd app)  -> my friend (authd app) -> their friend
OK  : Me              -> my friend (authd app) -> their friend
BAD : Me (authd app)  -> my friend             -> their friend
BAD : Me              -> my friend             -> their friend (authd app)
```

And to get multiple levels:

```
OK  : Me (authd app)  -> my friend             -> their friend (authd app)             -> their friend (authd app)             -> their friend (authd app)             -> their friend (authd app)

OK  : Me              -> my friend             -> their friend (authd app)             -> their friend              -> their friend (authd app)             -> their friend
```